# Update and Commit files by jenkin's [Pre build job]

Tags: .net, jenkins, svn, continuous-integration

Our code is in SVN repository say *C:\Project\A Project*

1. There are standard steps defined to update text file, so daily developer is manually modifying text file and committing on svn.
2. There is one windows form application : Its job is to generate new file, so daily developer is creating text file and committing on svn

After completion of point 1 and point 2 developer is starting jenkin build.

Can we do point 1 and point 2 somehow automated by jenkins means it will update the text file,create new file using windows form application once done commit itself and then start the build process.

Answer (score 0):

The first point is certainly doable. You could create a job which uses Bash/PowerShell (depending on what's available) to echo out whatever needs updating on the text file. Then use a [preferred SVN plugin](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=svn%20plugin%20jenkins) to commit your changes.

However, the second point is a little problematic. As far as I know, Widows Forms Apps are GUI based, and I'm not sure how you can automate navigating a GUI using Jenkins. If you have a command line alternative application (say, in C#), then its certainly possible. So I guess if you don't, you should just create one and move the logic of the Windows Forms App into it. Once that is done, you can simply run the compile the cs file

```
csc File_name.cs
```

run it, and commit to SVN as before.